# Spark failing caused by other Hadoop program

Tags: apache-spark

In my experience of using Spark on YARN, my spark program failed for many times because of other executing programs.

It seems other programs can deprive available memory from my executor instances. Thus Spark has no enough memory to continue.
This situation can happen frequently when cluster is being used fully.
And in a idle cluster, I can always run my spark program successfully.

So I'd like to what happened indeed and how can I avoid such things.